# Zend Framework 2 Doctrine 2 Module - No Service Locator in Controller Unit Tests

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, phpunit, zend-framework2

Here is my situation. I am developing a Zend Framework 2 application. I am using Doctrine module to communicate with a MySQL database. It is working fine in the application, I can load the entity manager from the service locator inside my controllers.

But inside my controller unit tests, the service locator doesn't exists and therefor all tests dealing with the database are failing with error message like this:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `get()` on a non-object in /Users/richardknop/Projects/myproject/module/Api/src/Api/Controller/UserController.php on line 19

I have narrowed the problem down to this method:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()
```

Which works in my controllers but returns NULL in unit tests.

This is my application.config.php:

```
<?php

return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'DoctrineModule',
        'DoctrineORMModule',
        'Api',
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths' => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
```

My local.php file with database connection details:

```
<?php

return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'port'     => '3306',
                    'user'     => 'root',
                    'password' => 'root',
                    'dbname'   => 'mydb',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

In my module.config.php I have:

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

And in my controllers I have this method to get the entity manager:

```
private $_em;

private function _getEntityManager()
{
    if (null === $this->_em) {
        $this->_em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
    }
    return $this->_em;
}
```

Now my unit tests. Here is the bootstrap file:

```
<?php

chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
include __DIR__ . '/../init_autoloader.php';
return Zend\Mvc\Application::init(include 'config/application.config.php');
```

And setUp method of my controller tests looks like:

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->_controller = new UserTokenController;
    $this->_request = new Request;
    $this->_routeMatch = new RouteMatch(array('controller' => 'user'));
    $this->_event = new MvcEvent();
    $this->_event->setRouteMatch($this->_routeMatch);
    $this->_controller->setEvent($this->_event);
}
```

An example controller unit test then looks like:

```
public function testGetListHttpStatusCode()
{
    $response = $this->_controller->dispatch($this->_request);
    $this->assertEquals(405, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

All tests that are not connecting to the database are passing. Tests where I am using entity manager are failing though with this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `get()` on a non-object in /Users/richardknop/Projects/myproject/module/Api/src/Api/Controller/UserController.php on line 19

This is line 19:

```
$this->_em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
```

And the reason it's failing is that `$this->getServiceLocator()` returns **`NULL`**.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dont' do this ins your bootstrap.php

```
return Zend\Mvc\Application::init(include 'config/application.config.php');` in your
```

but something like this:

```
chdir('/path/to/application/root');

// if you're using composer to install zf2
include_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
// if not using composer initialize your custom autoloading here

$configuration = include('config/application.config.php');
$serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig(
    isset($configuration['service_manager']) ? $configuration['service_manager'] : array()
));
$serviceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', $configuration);
$serviceManager->setFactory('ServiceListener', 'Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceListenerFactory');

$moduleManager = $serviceManager->get('ModuleManager');
$moduleManager->loadModules();
$serviceManager->setAllowOverride(true);

$application = $serviceManager->get('Application');
$event  = new MvcEvent();
$event->setTarget($application);
$event->setApplication($application)
    ->setRequest($application->getRequest())
    ->setResponse($application->getResponse())
    ->setRouter($serviceManager->get('Router'));
```

you could then create static methods in your test-case to set and get the event...

```
namespace My;

class TestCase extends \Some\Basic\TestCase
{
    protected static $_mvcEvent;

    public static function setMvcEvent(MvcEvent $e) {

        self::$_mvcEvent = $e;
    }

    public static function getMvcEvent() {

        return self::$_mvcEvent;
    }
}
```

...and inject it from the bootstrap.php file

```
My\TestCase::setMvcEvent($event);
```

and in your setUp method of the test simply do something like this

```
$this->_controller = new UserTokenController;
$this->_controller->setEvent(self::getMvcEvent());
$this->_controller->setServiceLocator(
    self::getMvcEvent()->getApplication()->getServiceManager()
);
```

also inject request etc. from event->application into controller here...

Comment: After all I have used a little bit different approach (but the main idea is the same, I just put more logic inside my Bootstrap.php for phpunit). But yours works as well.

Comment: mine also does a lot more, just reduced it to the basic requirements

Comment: Hi Andreas. I'm also using ZF2+Doctrine2 and am following your method. While the ServiceLocator is set, it seems that the event is not propagated to Controller plugins - the router for example is set in the serviceLocator but not in the redirect() plugin. Any ideas on how to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

Just extend your controller from
\Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase

It's init service locator and do a lot of other Controller's job. As well become available controller asserts, response asserts, CSS asserts etc. 
Details with examples look here http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.test.phpunit.html